# Can I fast-forward merge an entire branch chain into master?

Tags: git

If I have a chain of branches

master -> branchA -> branchB -> branchC -> branchD

is it possible to fast-forward merge branch D, and all of the branches in the chain between it and master (A, B, and C), into master in a single git command?

Comment: You can find this out yourself by using `git merge --ff-only`. If a fast-forward is possible it will do it, otherwise it will create an error message.

Comment: @randian don't take it personally, but "Can I do..." without telling anyone what you've already tried doing, is one type of a question that it does not make much sense asking in pages like SO ;) See [some bad and good examples](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#examples).

Comment: @mkrieger1 So the merge attempt automatically includes all branches between D and master, not just the changes between D and its immediate ancestor?

Comment: That depends on the exact command you are using I think. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is a sort of provisional yes.

The trick here is to realize that Git doesn't really care about *branches*.  Git really cares about *commits*.  When you talk about a "chain of branches", you're talking about a sort of optical illusion: you are seeing something Git doesn't.

To be properly precise here, we must define the term *branch*.  When we try, we find that this is a big problem.  Different people use the word differently, and one person will even use the word in more than one way, perhaps in the same sentence.  (See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))  But if we consciously step back a bit, trying to avoid the word "branch", and look at the way *commits* work, it all begins to make sense.

Each commit has a number.  The numbers aren't nice 1, 2, 3, style sequential numbers, though: they're random-looking hash IDs, like `ae46588be0cd730430dded4491246dfb4eac5557`.  (They're distinctly *not* random: they are checksums of the contents of each commit, so that every Git everywhere will compute the *same* hash ID for the *same* commit-bits.  That's the key magic in Git, really.)  There's no easy way to know which commit is which from the IDs.

So, what Git does is this: whenever you make a *new* commit, you make it from some existing commit.<sup>1</sup>  The *existing* commit is therefore the *parent* of the new commit.  Git stores, in the commit's metadata, the hash ID of the *parent* of the new commit.  This means that we can always start from the *last* commit and work backwards:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

If `H` stands in for the ID of the *last* commit, then `H` must contain, as its parent hash ID, the actual hash ID of commit `G`.  So if we can find `H` and read it, that gives us the ID of `G`.  We use the ID of `G` to find `G` and read it, and that contains the ID of `F`, and so on.

These backwards-pointing chains of commits are what are stored in the main Git database (along with the contents of each commit, also stored via hash IDs).  But that still leaves us with the puzzle of how we find the *last* commit.

---

The very first commit someone makes in a new repository does not fit this pattern, but the solution to that dilemma is obvious: just don't give it a parent at all.

---

#### Branch names find last commits

Git's answer to this puzzle is remarkably simple.  Each branch name holds one (1) hash ID.  That hash ID is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.

So, suppose we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L
```

as commits all in a line, and suppose that the *name* `master` points to commit `C`, the *name* `feature` points to commit `F`, the *name* `hack` points to commit `H`, and the *name* `last` points to commit `L`:

```
                 __feature
                .
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L   <-- last
       .              .
        ---master      --hack
```

Or we can draw it this way, perhaps more clearly, perhaps less clearly:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D--E--F   <-- feature
               \
                G--H   <-- hack
                    \
                     I--J--K--L   <-- last
```

Note that no commit, once made, can ever be changed.  *These commits* will always continue to point backwards like this: `L` to `K`, `K` to `J`, `J` to `I`, `I` to `H`, and so on.  We can make other new commits, perhaps using the same files and messages and so on, that point to other different commits, but they will have different hash IDs.

Now, the thing about *branch names* is that they *move*.  For `L` to be the last commit on branch `last`, if we make a *new* commit on `L`, the new commit must point back to `L`.  But if we `git checkout master`—which says to select commit `C`—and make a new commit *there*, that new commit must point back to existing commit `C`:

```
A--B--C--NEW   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D--E--F   <-- feature
               \
                G--H   <-- hack
                    \
                     I--J--K--L   <-- last
```

(Checking out a commit by using a branch name attaches the special name `HEAD` to the branch name, which is why I've added `HEAD` above.)

Going back to your original question, we now need to define the term *fast-forward*.  A *fast-forward operation*, in Git, means that we have some existing chain of commits, with a name—any name will do though branch names are the usual kind of name in question here—pointing to one of them, but then some more commits "after" that name, like this:

```
          V   <-- option1
         /
...--T--U   <-- name
         \
          W--X--Y--Z   <-- option2
```

To achieve the fast-forward operation, we tell Git: *move the name so that it points to one of the later commits, without forcing the name to move backwards.*  So here, we can tell Git to move `name` forward to `V`, or forward to any of `W-X-Y-Z`, and that's a fast-forward.  Let's pick `V`:

```
          V   <-- name, option1
         /
...--T--U
         \
          W--X--Y--Z   <-- option2
```

Now that we've done that, though, if we ask Git to move `name` so that it points to any of `W`, `X`, `Y`, or `Z`, Git will have to first "move backwards" from `V` to `U`, before moving forwards again.  That means the operation is *not* a fast-forward.

#### Fast-forwards aren't just from merge

While the `git merge` command can perform a fast-forward—and will do so automatically when it can—it's not the only part of Git that looks for fast-forward operations.  In particular, both `git fetch` and `git push` can adjust names.  The names `git fetch` adjusts are normally *remote-tracking names* rather than branch names, but the names that you use with `git push` usually tell some other Git repository to adjust *its* branch names, and those too will first check for fast-forward-ness.

#### Conclusion

In the end, it all comes down to your commit chains, and what exactly *you* mean by "branch".  If you can draw your branches the first way we did with `master`, `feature`, `hack`, and `last` above, you can then ask Git to move the name `master` forward:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D--E--F   <-- feature
               \
                G--H   <-- hack
                    \
                     I--J--K--L   <-- last
```

by running `git merge --ff-only last` or `git merge --ff-only hash-of-L`.  The `--ff-only` option tells `git merge` that if the operation *isn't* a fast-forward, this should fail.  Note that:

```
A--B--C--D--NEW   <-- master
          \
           E--...--L   <-- last
```

would indeed fail.  But `--ff-only` isn't perfect here.  Consider, for instance,
what happens if we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D--E--F--NEW   <-- feature
               \
                G--H   <-- hack
                    \
                     I--J--K--L   <-- last
```

You *can* fast-forward `master` to point to commit `L`, giving:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--NEW   <-- feature
                \
                 G--H   <-- hack
                     \
                      I--J--K--L   <-- last, master (HEAD)
```

But `feature` remains one commit "ahead of" `master`, as commit `NEW`—which points back to `F`—is only available by starting at `feature` and working backwards.